# removing whitespaces not working MySQL. Used TRIM() and REPLACE()

Tags: mysql, replace, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace

Take a look : [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/41735)

```
select IF((TRIM(replace(' IKECHUKWU  OSUJI',' ',''))=TRIM(replace('IKECHUKWU OSUJI',' 
',''))),"same","diff");
select IF((TRIM(replace(' Aman Minhas  ',' ',''))=TRIM(replace(' Aman Min has',' 
',''))),"same","diff");
```

[image: Err image]
The first query returns diff. The second returns same. Its some weird spacing issue, cant seem to understand why this behaviour.

Comment: You know your fiddle is empty?

Comment: Oops! Corrected.. Thanks juergen

Comment: Executed this in FIDDLE (as you recommended) and got "same" and "same". The only difference was that after I pasted your code, I removed the line breaks in the Fiddle window.

Are you certain you can reproduce this (assuming you remove line breaks when you execute)?

Comment: I did, I added an image for reference .. it seems like some crazy spacing issue..

Comment: Try just selecting the result of each of those 4 expressions.

Comment: I tried Select TRIM(replace(' IKECHUKWU  OSUJI',' ','')) , TRIM(replace('IKECHUKWU OSUJI',' ','')); It looks identical..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first string has a tab in it:

```
select IF((TRIM(replace(' IKECHUKWU  OSUJI',' ',''))
                                   ^ this is actually a tab in the Fiddle
```

You can get rid of it with an additional `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(myString, ' ', ''), '\t', '')
```

The `\t` is a special literal. Other special literals such as newline or ASCII NUL may impact you as well. Literals are listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html).